# Define new class at runtime in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to define a temporary class at runtime (with the goal of creating mock objects for testing). For example:

```
class Foo {
    func bar(classType) {
        class Mock: classType {
            // class body
        }
        let m = Mock()
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Swift currently? If not directly, perhaps through generics?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like something one might do in Ruby. But Swift is the opposite of Ruby: every type has to be completely defined at compile time.

Your code is certainly legal if `classType` is known at compile time: there is nothing wrong with defining a class within a function (though of course it is then only in scope while the rest of the function runs). But the superclass of that class must be well-defined at compile time; it cannot be postponed until runtime.

Comment: What if `classType` is a generic type, such as `<T: UIViewController>`

Comment: Additionally, what type would `classType` need to be in order for Mock to inherit from it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no; or perhaps, no and yes.

As noted in @matt's answer, Swift typing is very static. The existence of a generics system in Swift doesn't change this: all typing is still static in that it's known at compile time, for example, which `T` is in use when you use a generic like `func foo<T>(t: T)` or create an `Array<T>`. The *compiler* must have knowledge of a class to create a subclass, so you can't use dynamic runtime information there. (And even if it were possible to subclass a generic type parameter, there'd have to be constraints on that parameter that give the compiler static knowledge of the possible superclasses.)

However, Swift uses and interoperates with the Objective-C runtime (on Apple platforms; sorry, open-source Swift-on-Linux-etc users). So you can use [ObjC Runtime APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html) to [create classes](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html) and populate them with methods and properties, dynamically at run time, based on knowledge only available at run time. In theory you can even use those APIs and the resulting classes from Swift code... of course, it won't be very pretty, because your Swift code will by definition not at compile time have static type information for your dynamically created classes.

Comment: This answer is very detailed. What would make it even more amazing though, would be if you showed an example of using the ObjC Runtime from Swift to create a class and populate it at runtime.